# Course based on Angular Material version

Tags: angular, angular-material, version

I am trying to watch a course about Angular Material and after checking out their website, it looks like Angular Material 8 is the latest version.

I found 2 courses about Angular Material from 2 different authors that I like but none of them are for angular material version 8.

The author I like more has a course that uses Angular Material 5 (i assume it's with angular 5) and then there is that other author that uses Angular Material 7 (maybe with Angular 7 if there is any ng material - ng association at all)...

**QUESTIONS**:

- How much does it matter what version of Angular Material do I use?
- Can I still follow along the Angular Material 5 course with a version
  8 on my local machine? Or should I go with the Angular Material 7
  instead?
- Or should I try to find a course with Angular Material 8?
- Are the major Angular Material versions associated/the same with the
  Angular versions?

Comment: 5 to 7 differs quite a bit. Biggest changes comes in version 6. As I recall, some of these are - RxJs uses lettable operators, Angular changes HttpClient quite a bit. Nothing special pops in about Material, though. So if you don't know RxJs and Angular well, might be better to start on 6+ version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's always better to us the latest angular material. A lot of issues are solved and the external libraries (at least the official) are adding new components following the latest versions.
2. Same principles apply, but the apis are changed quite a lot, as did the usage, so I would advise against it. Better go with angular material 7. I have recently migrated from 6 to 7 and from 7 to 8 with little to none changes (only some overrided scss stuff).
3. Don't bother.
4. Yes they are. The material dependencies are tighly coupled with the angular version. Check https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0 and tick use material. You will find that you must also update to version 8.0. Pretty much the same for all upgrades.

Comment: thanks for your answers: it helps... in regards to your answer to the second question you said there were little to no changes to upgrade from 6 to 7 and then 7 to 8... what about from 5 to 6? the reason why im asking for that is the tutorial talking about angular material 5/angular 5 is so more profesionally made that i wonder if i could at least get the concepts and not follow along anymore, in order to get a nice understanding of how to use them in general

Comment: Concepts do indeed remain the same and material 5 is still supported in docs etc. 5 to 6 maintains the same controls. Beware of observables as there is quite the change between syntax from rjxs 5 to 6 so it might get a bit confusing in practice. The idea is the same, the execution differs in syntax.